# Simple 2D Java Game

Tags: java, swing, draw, shapes

I'm trying to create a java game in which balls randomly drop from the top of the screen and we need to catch the balls using a catcher which is located at the bottom of the screen.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to actually draw this onto my JFrame.

I've got a class for my 'catcher', 'ball', 'game space' and I would like to put it all together.

How do I draw my 'catcher' onto my screen?

Currently, I have a 'Game' class which looks like this.

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

GameScreen gameScreen;
Catcher playerOneCatcher;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    new Game();
}

public Game() {

    super("CATCH");
    setSize(640,480);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    addKeyListener(this);


    this.gameScreen = new GameScreen();
    this.playerOneCatcher = new Catcher(40, 10); 


}
```

I've tried something like this in my Catcher class...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(positionX, positionY, this.width, this.height);
}
```

However, its not showing on my screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've retagged as "swing" as this is not "game-development" but generic Swing problem you are having. What class does your Catcher subclass? Have you added your Catcher instance to your JFrame? Show more code, I guess.

Comment: I've added some more code - hopefully this makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rethink your strategy here. Swing is a component framework, with most components intended for building user interfaces. These components are not optimised for what's typically required in games. You want to look into double-buffering, sprites etc. The way to go will be to read up on Graphics2D class (or abandon Swing altogether!)

However answering to your question - if Catcher is a Swing component - you need to add it to the "parent" component, e.g. like this:

```
this.add(playerOneCatcher);
```

Same goes to `gameScreen` but from your snippet it is not obvious what this component is. I hope this helps.

Also, check this out for some ideas: [2D Java Game. Moving sprite above tiled images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189267/2d-java-game-moving-sprite-above-tiled-images)

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you call `super.paintComponent (g)` ? That can cause a few bugs.
2. Did you call `invalidate ()` or `repaint ()` to repaint the thing you are painting on? I hope you have a special JComponent, and you are not drawing on a JFrame. That is NOT good.